# Call to Web API getting slower and slower with each call on Angular 7 app

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

My Angular c# app makes a call to a web API and hits a stored proc. The C# part of the app executes quickly, but the 'Content Download' is getting slower and slower with each call.

[image: Taken from chrome console]

I have a Angular service that calls the web API;

```
getInvestorsToFunds(params): Observable<InvestorToFund[]> {  
    let body = JSON.stringify({ params });  
    return this.http.post<InvestorToFund[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Investor/getInvestorsToFunds', body)   
     .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
 }
```

And I call that from my component;

```
 let x = forkJoin(  
  this.investorService.getInvestorsToFunds(params)
).subscribe(t => { 
  this.investorToFunds = t[0] as InvestorToFund[]; 
});
```

Any ideas on why each call just gets slower and slower?

Comment: If you are sure that the issue is on backend side, why do we have angular code ? Maybe you are not that sure ? So you should measure timing on your controller not on the client API :)

Comment: There is only one http request sent? If yes then maybe you can remove the forkJoin.

Comment: do you really need 7 mb of data? even the first call is too slow. why do you need so much data and why do you make repeated calls to the same controller method?

Comment: a)I put a breakpoint on my controller, and the stored proc is executing and returning data very quickly. I'm sure it's in the transfer of data from the server to the client.
b) There are other requests, removed for simplicity. On some components it is called by itself not in a forkjoin.
c) It's a finance app, and I need fresh data as it can change. I could maybe reduce the amount, but I was hoping someone might have an idea as to why it could happen. On a good day it returns the data in 3 seconds on the first call. I can live with that. Just curious why it slows down with each further call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got to the bottom of this and I'll post my answer for any poor soul who faces the same issue.

I read into memory leaks and the Chrome tools for taking snapshots. Sure enough my memory usage was increasing over time with each page hit. This meant that less memory was available for my app, throttling the data input from my API.

Turns out one of my plug-ins was causing an issue - https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js-angular2. I was on version 6 - when I updated to version 7 this stopped the memory leaks and the API call executed in about 3 seconds every time, no matter how many pages I clicked on.

Helpful articles;

https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Comment: Hi there, I am in kind of same mess with ng9 not able to figure the cause yet, did removing plugin fixed it for you or the memory leaks ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a memory leak. You need to unsubscribe from subscriptions

```
class A implements OnDestroy {
    protected ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    }
```

And on EACH subscription

```
  this.subscription.takeUntil( this.ngUnsubscribe ).subscribe( _ => _ );
```

This way, when you move away from a component, the ngOnDestroy is run and all your subscriptions are cleared from the memory.

PS. I had the same issue, when I first started. No issues after I implemented this, all is running smooth as butter.

Answer (score -7):

> Any ideas on why each call just gets slower and slower?

The time you are seeing is the backend response time. The backend is getting slower and slower and any changes to your frontend code will not make it faster.

## Fix

Fix the backend

Comment: That's not true I don't think. I put a breakpoint on my controller when all the data is fetched. It happens in less than a second every time. I click continue then the slow process of getting the 7MB of data from the server to the client begins.

Comment: Does this problem occur in your dev environment or is the WebApi on a prod env?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel It occurs on both. My localhost (with a local SQL Server) is slower than the prod server.

Comment: On the prod server the data is gZipped, compressed to 850kb. But is also getting slower with each subsequent call. Starts at 2 seconds but a few calls later it's up to 10 seconds. Frustrating!